# R - Data Frame & Prediction with confidence level

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression, predict

I have a data set with the following columns.

Charge | Age | BMI | Female | Children | Smoker | WinterSprings | WinterPark | Oviedo

I created the following regression equation

```
Chargeslm <- lm(Charges ~., data = insurance)
summary(Chargeslm)
```

I now want to predict the amount of medical expenses associated with a new policy, applying a 95% confidence interval.

Below is my code:

```
TEST <- data.frame(Age = 35,
                   BMI = 26,
                   Children = 1,
                   Female = 1,
                   Smoker = 0,
                   City = "sanford")
               
predict(Chargeslm, newdata = TEST, interval = "confidence", level =.95)
```

I then get the following error:

```
error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'WinterSprings' not found
```

Comment: Your model includes all variables in the original data.frame, so your TEST data.frame for prediction must have the same variables used in the model, so you need to add WinterSprings | WinterPark | Oviedo in TEST or remove them from the estimation. This is what the error message is saying.

Comment: @JilberUrbina the cities are dummy variables (Winter Springs | Winter Park | Ovideo) with the default city being "Sanford" which isn't in the data set. I tried including WinterSprings in the data.frame with a 0 but I get the same error